# How would i create a shared token cache to be used with MSAL library?

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I would like to store mail token related data in a cache on the application level. The token should be accessible from multiple sessions.

If it is not possible to store this data in a shared cache, would it be possible to create a token cache that persists to a database and would that be a feasible idea?